# ASP.NET - Hyperlink relative path to current URL on ASPX page not in code behind

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

I tried this one but the href code is not generated

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlPrev" NavigateUrl="<%# this.Request.Url %>" runat="server" />
```

Is there any way to do this on aspx page not in the code behind?

Comment: Could u elaborate (possibly on examples) which URL you want to appear there?

Comment: "hlPrev" presume the previous page...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If **hlPrev** is located outside of **DataBound** controls like **GridView**, there are two problems in our code -

1. You want to use `<%= %>` instead of `<%# %>` which is used in **DataBound** controls.
2. You cannot use `<%= %>` to set property of a server control. Basically, you cannot mix `runat="server"` with `<%= %>`.

### Solution:

```
<a href="<%= Request.Url.ToString() %>">Click Me</a>
```